# CSS selector for a child element whose parent element has a certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to specify CSS in a style sheet file for the `strong` element inside a `div` as in code below. This `strong` element is inside a parent `div` whose class is `commandBar`.

```
<strong>Outside Div</strong>
<div class='commandBar'>
    <button class='dBtn'>Delete</button>
    <strong>My Name</strong>
    <button class='aBtn'>Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To select `strong` elements that are descendants of an element with class `commandBar`, use the [descendant combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) along with a [class selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#class-html):

```
.commandBar strong
```

In order to only select direct children `strong` elements, use the [child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators):

```
.commandBar > strong
```

Depending on your markup, you may also want to specify the element type that has the class `.commandBar` (in this case, `div`):

```
div.commandBar strong
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Descendant Selector** The descendant selector matches all elements that are descendants of a specified element.
>
> The following example selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>`
>   elements:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> div p {
>     background-color: yellow;
> }
> ```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

so in your case you would use:

```
.commandBar strong{
/* your css style here */
}
```

Comment: If you're going to copy text, please add attribution. And at least copy it correctly.